# How can I delete a droplet provisioned by salt-stack

Tags: digital-ocean, salt-stack

I have a training environment that I use salt-stack to deploy lab machines. Is there a way to destroy using a salt command or will I have to use the do api cli for that?

I deployed using the salt-cloud configuration as outlined in the digital ocean community guides.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/saltstack-infrastructure-configuring-salt-cloud-to-spin-up-digitalocean-resources#create-the-ssh-key-file

Comment: how were the instances created? through salt-cloud? through digital ocean and then you put the minions on them? it helps to know how they were created beyond "used salt-stack" to know how to remove them. salt-stack has A LOT of different ways of setting up minions.

Comment: yes thru the salt-cloud commands

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering that you created the instances through salt-cloud. when you issued salt-cloud you most likely used either `-p` or `-m`. `-p` being profile and `-m` being map. both can be reversed with `-d` for destroy. for the map you also have to pass the map again. but when instances were created with -p you only need to use the instance name.

see https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/cloud/basic.html#destroying-a-vm for more info on destroy.

not shown is deleting maps which would be `salt-cloud -d -m <mapfile>` if you use the cloud runner there is also cloud.destroy runner function https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.cloud.html#salt.runners.cloud.destroy

there is also https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cloud.html#salt.modules.cloud.destroy

all of these options will delete the instance through the cloud system. and remove the key from the salt master